# How to change the default icons in openlayers 6 and ol-ext?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I need to change the default icons (zoom and attribution) and the search icon (with search box) for ol-ext on my Map. In which way can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zoom control does not use icons, the + and - are text, but you can specify an element using the `zoomInLabel` and `zoomOutLabel` options https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_control_Zoom-Zoom.html  In the case of attribution the equivalent options are `label` and
`collapseLabel` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_control_Attribution-Attribution.html  In ol-ext the icon is the `background-image` in the css, so you would need to use you own css to update it.